# JXMultiSplitPane causes repaint during slider adjustment?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, swingx

I seem to be getting frequent repaint requests during adjustment of the splitter in [`JXMultiSplitPane`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-42-2006-10-15/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMultiSplitPane.html). (see program below)

Why?

I have `setContinuousLayout(false)`.

---

Just to clarify: I understand the repaint should occur *after* the split-panes are resized. But *during* splitter adjustment, nothing is being resized; the splitter is moving around on the screen.

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMultiSplitPane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.MultiSplitLayout;

public class MultiVerticalPane<T extends Component> extends JPanel
{
    final private List<T> components;
    public MultiVerticalPane(List<? extends T> components,
            List<Double> weights)
    {
        this.components = new ArrayList<T>(components);
        final int n = this.components.size();
        if (weights != null && weights.size() != n)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "weights and components should have same length");

        JXMultiSplitPane msp = new JXMultiSplitPane();
        msp.setContinuousLayout(false);
        msp.getMultiSplitLayout().setModel(createSplitModel(weights));
        int i = 0;
        for (T component : components)
        {
            msp.add(component, nodeTitle(i++));
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(msp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private MultiSplitLayout.Split createSplitModel(
            List<Double> weights) 
    {
        LinkedList<MultiSplitLayout.Node> nodes = 
            new LinkedList<MultiSplitLayout.Node>();
        int i = 0;
        double wtot = 0;
        for (double w : weights)
        {
            wtot += w;
        }
        for (double w : weights)
        {           
            if (i > 0)
                nodes.addFirst(new MultiSplitLayout.Divider());
            MultiSplitLayout.Leaf leaf = 
                new MultiSplitLayout.Leaf(nodeTitle(i++));
            leaf.setWeight(w/wtot);
            nodes.addFirst(leaf);
        }
        MultiSplitLayout.Split split = 
            new MultiSplitLayout.Split();
        split.setRowLayout(false);
        split.setChildren(nodes);
        return split;
    }
    private String nodeTitle(int i) {
        return String.format("%02d", i);
    }

    /************ test methods *************/

    private interface Painter
    {
        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds);
    }

    static private class RelativeGraphics
    {
        final private Graphics g;
        final private double xofs;
        final private double yofs;
        final private double xscale;
        final private double yscale;
        private double cx;
        private double cy;

        public RelativeGraphics(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds)
        {
            this.g = g;
            this.cx = 0;
            this.cy = 0;
            this.xofs = bounds.getMinX();
            this.yofs = bounds.getMaxY();
            this.xscale = bounds.getWidth();
            this.yscale = -bounds.getHeight();
        }
        public void moveTo(double x, double y)
        {
            this.cx = x;
            this.cy = y;
        }
        public void lineTo(double x, double y)
        {
            this.g.drawLine(
                (int)(this.cx*this.xscale+this.xofs),
                (int)(this.cy*this.yscale+this.yofs),
                (int)(x*this.xscale+this.xofs),
                (int)(y*this.yscale+this.yofs)
            );
            moveTo(x,y);
        }           
        public void rmoveTo(double dx, double dy)
        {
            moveTo(this.cx+dx, this.cy+dy);
        }           
        public void rlineTo(double dx, double dy)
        {
            lineTo(this.cx+dx, this.cy+dy);
        }           
    }

    // adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Java
    static private class HilbertCurve
    {
        final private RelativeGraphics rg;
        final private double d;
        public HilbertCurve(RelativeGraphics rg, int level)
        {
            this.rg = rg;
            double d0 = 1.0;
            for (int i = level; i > 0; i--)
                d0 /= 2;
            this.d = d0;
            rg.rmoveTo(d0/2, d0/2);
            drawCurveUp(level);
        }
        private void drawCurveUp(int n) 
        {           
            if (n > 0) {
                drawCurveLeft(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(0, this.d);
                drawCurveUp(n-1);      this.rg.rlineTo(this.d, 0);
                drawCurveUp(n-1);      this.rg.rlineTo(0, -this.d);
                drawCurveRight(n-1);
            }
        }

        private void drawCurveLeft(int n)
        {
            if (n > 0) {
                drawCurveUp(n-1);      this.rg.rlineTo(this.d, 0);
                drawCurveLeft(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(0, this.d);
                drawCurveLeft(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(-this.d, 0);
                drawCurveDown(n-1);
            }
        }

        private void drawCurveRight(int n)
        {
            if (n > 0) {
                drawCurveDown(n-1);     this.rg.rlineTo(-this.d, 0);
                drawCurveRight(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(0, -this.d);
                drawCurveRight(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(this.d, 0);
                drawCurveUp(n-1);
            }
        }

        private void drawCurveDown(int n)
        {
            if (n > 0) {
                drawCurveRight(n-1);    this.rg.rlineTo(0, -this.d);
                drawCurveDown(n-1);     this.rg.rlineTo(-this.d, 0);
                drawCurveDown(n-1);     this.rg.rlineTo(0, this.d);
                drawCurveLeft(n-1);
            }
        }
    }

    static private class HilbertPainter implements Painter
    {
        final private int level;
        public HilbertPainter(int level) { this.level = level; }
        @Override public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds) {
            new HilbertCurve(
                new RelativeGraphics(g,
                    new Rectangle(new Point(0,0),bounds.getSize())),
                this.level);
        }
    }

    static private class PainterPanel extends JPanel
    {
        final private Painter painter;

        public PainterPanel(Painter painter)
        {
            this.painter = painter;
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            this.painter.paint(g, getBounds());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { test(); }
    private static void test() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultiVerticalPane test");
        List<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
        List<Double> weights = Arrays.asList(1.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,8.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            panels.add(new PainterPanel(new HilbertPainter(i+4)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    @Override public void paint(Graphics g, 
                            Rectangle bounds)
                    {
                        super.paint(g, 
                            new Rectangle(bounds.getLocation(),
                                new Dimension(bounds.width, 
                                    bounds.height-10)));
                        g.drawString(String.format("%d", this.count++),
                                0, bounds.height);
                    }
                }
            ));
        }       
        MultiVerticalPane<Component> mvp = 
            new MultiVerticalPane<Component>(panels, weights);
        mvp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360,720));
        frame.setContentPane(mvp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting question, I think. I wonder what others have to say about it.

Comment: @Jason S did you observe that using this method actually saves you lots of repaints, and the repainting effect is different? Also setContinuousLayout(true) doesn't cause other components to repaint after mouse release.

Comment: @Jason S why do you wrote Own method with name Painter, method with same name are implemented for NimbusL&F from Java1.6_02X, SwingX has own Painter, but I think that depends of Native OS and L&F too

Comment: @mKorbel: "why do you wrote Own method with name Painter" Why not? (I assume you mean "interface" rather than "method") I wanted to separate the logic that draws from the object that is drawn upon.

Comment: @Jason S  on WinXP Java 1.6.0._22/1.5.0_22 unknow version for swingx.jar works (fast resize flickering on old fullHD monitors (2pcs), but JXMultiSplitPane works for all 5 areas), just update your GPU drivers

Comment: @mKorbel  This might actually be the case as on my laptop I see nothing bad with painting/repainting, and I am up to date with all? Did you tested it yourself on some older computers? If this is the case then maybe you should write all your findings in an extended, more detailed way in an answer?

Comment: @Boro  :-) no there isn't way something to tested on old PC throught WE (hp530d), erghhht maybe there is way to test that right now on this sleepingBeauty http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=4620

Comment: @mKorbel it looks nice :) It is so small kind of like a toy for children :)

Comment: @Boro my magic globe is off, no issues, works and why not, just for joke I'll add java.swing.Timer with quick repaints cca 100ms :-)

Comment: @Boro not this's excelent HightEndPcCreature for presentations on place, if works here, then works "everywhere", excluding some OP's isn't it (Jason S sorry for uncalled-for prank, that means as joke)

Comment: @Boro  I'm so stupid, there no problem with Graphics but with Swing painting heavens I'm blind 'public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds) {...}' , must be 'public void paintComponent(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds) {...}' , sure without changes to Monitor on 250ms Timer bases, now I'm outta of this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `setContinuousLayout()` affects `revalidate()`, not `repaint()`.

Answer (score 1):

*Its not a 'direct' answer. I just put it here since I run out of space in a comment.*

I do not think it is too frequent? Why would you think that did you compare it with any other component?

What I think is that every resize a component detects it calls repaint. On top of it goes how a layout manager handles resizing. Please observe that when, for example, you resize the top most panel and are dragging it down it is very rarely repainted, which you cannot say about his neighbour. The situation is reversed when you drag the slider up.

BTW: Might I ask why would you worry about how often and which part of the split pane is repainted?

*Please bear in mind that I am not an expert on the internals of the repaint mechanism of this component but I would doubt that SwingX guys would step away from the defaults in this regards.*

Comment: nobody knows, but here comings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144232/javaswing-efficient-overlay-of-rectangle-or-other-sprite

Comment: "What I think is that every resize a component detects it calls repaint" -- Sure, but the resizing doesn't happen until *after* the adjustment of the splitter is complete.

Comment: "Might I ask why would you worry about how often" -- Because complex painting takes a long time (see the other question 6144232 that mKorbel linked too), and I'd rather not bother doing bitblts to cache a drawing if I don't have to.

Comment: @mKorbel thanks and thanks for linking me to the other question.