# Custom range to use with JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to create a jslider that moves withing the following ranges.

```
[-x,-1)[1,x]
```

In short I don't want the values -1 and 0 to be valid values for the JSlider.
But the values from x to -1 should be allowed, and 1 to x should be allowed.

I'm trying to not write hacky code, so I don't want to write a function in the UI code that just gets the value from a different (continuous) range, and then transforms it to the range I want with a bunch of it statements.

Ideally, I should just be able to call `slider.getValue()` and know that the return value will be in the range I described above.

Comment: Added swing tag. So more people who have experience with this will see it.

Comment: Should have definitely thought to add that tag. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: @Varun Madiath what did you try so far? Do you have some code?

Comment: @Varun Madiath I think the ranges should be `[-x,-1)[1,x)` instead of `[x,-1)[1,x)`, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit that, also the final x should be inclusive

Comment: OK what about -1 it still should be excluded? For reference I updated the code to reflect you latest range edit.

Comment: Currently I've got the really ugly method of doing everything with the return value from the slider.getValue() method. I simply changed the boundaries tp [-(x-2),x] and then subtracted 2 from the value if x was less than or equal to 0.

Comment: I guess I could use the method above and override `DefaultBoundedRangeModel`'s `setValue` implementation, but I'm trying to find a better way to do this if possible.

Comment: Please let me know if you will figure out something nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must do this value adjustment yourself perhaps within overridden method `setValue()`?

Try out this code:

```
    int x = 10;
    @Override
    public void setValue(int n)
    {
        if((n >= -x && n < -1)|| (n =< x && n >= 1))
        {   
            super.setValue(n);
            System.out.println("OI in setValue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking that code like this really belongs in the model. Don't you?

Comment: @Varun Madiath you are right. It would be much better. Check out `BoundedRangeModel` then which you can then set to the slider. It has setValue method thus I believe you could copy the code over to your model.

Comment: Great, the problem I see with your code, is that if the user were to drag the slide to a value of -1 or 0, the slider would simply bounce back to it's prior position. Which will confuse the user.

Comment: @Varun Madiath well you are right. It was just a suggestion a sample code to start with :) now you should handle special cases yourself, i.e. see where it is released and set to the closes possible :)

Answer (score 2):

A slider's value is just the ratio between the thumb's current position and the sliders width, in pixels. IIUC, you have three ranges, `[-x,-1)`, `[-1,1)` and `[1,x]`, so you'll need two thumbs. You might look at [`JXMultiThumbSlider`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-44-2006-10-29/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMultiThumbSlider.html), which supports a [`MultiThumbModel`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-44-2006-10-29/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/multislider/MultiThumbModel.html).

Addendum: For a related use-case, I started with [*How to Write a Custom Swing Component*](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html). It's laborious, but it may produce a cleaner result.

Comment: are you "familiar" with java.net, why there everything d*i*e*d +1

Comment: @mKorbel: Excellent point, but the API might serve as a guide to any extant source or examples.

Comment: big and largiest project are unaccessible for example SwingX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154504/jxmultisplitpane-causes-repaint-during-slider-adjustment, that's horror suck swingx.jar ...

Comment: @mKorbel hi guys do you have a link to an image or a simple example with this component. Would be nice to see it. I think, that there was at least a year ago a jar demonstrating all SwingX components, am I right?

Comment: @Boro: I _thought_ I saw one on SO, but I can't find it.